# Apply a regex function on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe in pandas like:

```
0                       1                   2
([0.8898668778942382    0.89533945283595]   0)
([1.2632564814188714    1.0207660696232244] 0)
([1.006649166957976     1.1180973832359227] 0)
([0.9653632916751714    0.8625538463644129] 0)
([1.038366333873932     0.9091449796555554] 0)
```

All values are strings. I want to remove all special characters and convert to double. I want to apply a function that remove all special character excepr the dot like

```
import re
re.sub('[^0-9.]+', '',x)
```

so I want to apply this in all cell of the dataframe. How can I do it? I find df.applymap function but I don't know how to pass the string as argument. I tried

```
def remSp(x): 
    re.sub('^[0-9]+', '',x)

df.applymap(remSp())
```

but I don't know how to pass the cells to the function. Is there a better way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Pass `remSp` wihtout the `()`, the argument is the function itself, not the result of the call

Comment: The applymap function then will call `remSp` on every item in your dataframe

Comment: You pass are looking for `df.applymap(remSp)`, note, you don't want to *call* the function before passing it, `.applymap` *takes a function as a parameter*. Note, you may want to add a `.` to your group in the regex pattern...

Comment: I tried this [ df.applymap(remSp) ]but return a dataframe with all values None

Comment: @MichailN yes, because `remSp` **always returns `None`** the way you've defined it...

Comment: Better answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114275/4909087)... one liner too... feel free to accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why cant use the default replace method on df directly with regex i.e

```
df = df.replace('[^\d.]', '',regex=True).astype(float)
```

```
          0         1    2
0  0.889867  0.895339  0.0
1  1.263256  1.020766  0.0
2  1.006649  1.118097  0.0
3  0.965363  0.862554  0.0
4  1.038366  0.909145  0.0
```

Which is still faster than the other answers.

Comment: [Yes, this is better... nice job.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113355/apply-a-regex-function-in-a-pandas-dataframe/46113474?noredirect=1#comment79190559_46113355)

Comment: I tried this line and it is giving me the following error: "could not convert string to float" Any thought?

Comment: After this try remove `.astype(float)` and use `.apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce'),1)`, the error might be because of some `nan` or unknown strings present in the columns.

Answer (score 3):

Using `applymap`

```
In [814]: df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\d.]+', '', x)).astype(float)
Out[814]:
          0         1    2
0  0.889867  0.895339  0.0
1  1.263256  1.020766  0.0
2  1.006649  1.118097  0.0
3  0.965363  0.862554  0.0
4  1.038366  0.909145  0.0
```

Using `transform`

```
In [809]: df.transform(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[^\d.]+', '')).astype(float)
Out[809]:
          0         1    2
0  0.889867  0.895339  0.0
1  1.263256  1.020766  0.0
2  1.006649  1.118097  0.0
3  0.965363  0.862554  0.0
4  1.038366  0.909145  0.0
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Even though I like one liners your answer performs better so well done sir!

Comment: @MichailN [Added benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46113474/4909087). Seriously... one liners are overrated.

Comment: @COLDSPEED sometimes style is better than performance but anyway you are correct

Comment: @MichailN Before I had to literally barge my way into another person's answer, my answer had no votes... seriously,.. no one likes loops or what? :-(

Comment: @COLDSPEED No love for loops from me! One-liners rule!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Shiva, I can understand you. But, you do realize the original intent of OP was how to use applymap. If speed is sole motive of all questions, we can always go back to Numpy/Numba versions. Readability scores above marginal x improvement IMHO for the usecases I work on. And,  their is good possiblity, you want to return a copy and not modify original df.

Comment: @JohnGalt yes, and that's why I upvoted your answer. However, I believe in a balance between the two. Most people working with pandas would not be doing so unless they had a lot of data to work with... you don't want to offer a slow solution in the name of code golf. Just my two cents. I appreciate you being such a sport :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ -- I agree, I obsess about perf myself ;)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over columns, call `str.replace`.

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = df[c].str.replace('[^\d.]', '')

df = df.astype(float)
df
          0         1  2
0  0.889867  0.895339  0
1  1.263256  1.020766  0
2  1.006649  1.118097  0
3  0.965363  0.862554  0
4  1.038366  0.909145  0
```

Unfortunately, `pandas` does not yet support string accessor operations on the dataframe as a whole, so the alternative to looping over columns would be something slower like a lambdised `applymap/transform`.

---

**Performance**

## Small

```
100 loops, best of 3: 2.04 ms per loop  # applymap 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop  # transform
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 ms per loop  # looped str.replace
```

## Large (*`df * 10000`*)

```
1 loop, best of 3: 618 ms per loop  # applymap 
1 loop, best of 3: 658 ms per loop  # transform
1 loop, best of 3: 341 ms per loop  # looped str.replace
1 loop, best of 3: 212 ms per loop  # df.replace
```

Comment: You might want to be careful when bechmarking inplace operation and functions that return a copy. In former case, after the first replace is done, remaining 99 loops of tests are practically not doing the same operation, get it?

Comment: @JohnGalt Let me re-run with 1 loop.

Comment: And, check if moving `astype(float)` inside the loop improves it further.

Comment: @JohnGalt Reran with a single loop. Also, astype into the loop makes it much worse.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ what about my answer?